# Resize and Crop, Out of memory

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have this little method, that will resize an image and crop it, but it has suddenly started giving me OutOfMemory Exception, after it's been working for hours. What am I doing wrong? I think the Exception is on `return bmp.Clone(cropArea, bmp.PixelFormat);`

```
    private static Bitmap Resize(Bitmap image, int width, int height)
    {
        double scaleH = (double)height / image.Height;
        double scaleW = (double)width / image.Width;
        double scale = 1.0;
        if (image.Width * scaleH >= width)
            scale = scaleH;
        else if (image.Height * scaleW >= height)
            scale = scaleW;

        var scaleWidth = (int)(image.Width * scale);
        var scaleHeight = (int)(image.Height * scale);

        using (var bmp = new Bitmap((int)scaleWidth, (int)scaleHeight))
        {
            using (var graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                graph.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight));
            }
            int xStart = (bmp.Width - width) / 2;
            int yStart = (bmp.Height - height) / 2;
            Rectangle cropArea = new Rectangle(xStart, yStart, width, height);
            return bmp.Clone(cropArea, bmp.PixelFormat);
        }
    }
```

Solution it was a rounding problem, the crop rectangle was bigger then the image it self

```
    var scaleWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(image.Width * scale);
    var scaleHeight = (int)Math.Ceiling(image.Height * scale);
```

Comment: Do you have any other areas where you are using resources that require a clean up? Just because the exception occurred at a point does not mean that is where the leak is, just where the system ran out of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I thought it was because of a memory leak you had in the original question

```
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(width, height);
...
target = bmp.Clone(cropArea, bmp.PixelFormat);
```

You needed to assign the clone to a temp var, dispose the instance target is pointing to and then return target.

If you actually did use target for something you would want to do this

```
temp = bmp.Clone(cropArea, bmp.PixelFormat);
target.Dipose();
target = temp;
```

But you noted that is no longer the issue (your updated example doesn't have this problem) from what I can tell the code in your question does not seem to be the issue, you probably have a memory leak, MSDN has some more info about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2(v=vs.100).aspx). If you provide the code where you are using objects that wrap unmanaged resources I might be able to figure out if it is a memory leak.

#### Another Possibility

It is also possible that the bitmap is so large that you are running out of memory available to your program, it would be easier to tell if you could let us know more information about the bitmap that the program fails on

Comment: Hmm i don't understand what you are trying to say with the last code example?

Comment: the reason i instansiate target is because of var g = Graphics.FromImage(target)

Comment: @DoomStone, I know I just corrected it, my mistake. The variable `target` is being assigned a pointer to a new instance of a bitmap created by the clone method, you need to make sure you dispose the object `target` is pointing to before assigning the variable a new object, otherwise you are leaving the GC to dispose of the resources

Comment: I saw that the g = was a left over from my old method, i have removed it, and also the target. but i still get the error on the clone. I have updated the first post!

Comment: The bitmap is 1.46Mb, 1920x1200

Comment: OK that isn't large enough to cause it to fail, where do you dispose the variable that holds the original `image`?

Comment: I figured it out see my first post :D